# my camera doesnt turn on while Coding in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am beginner in CV. My camera crash every time.
I mean camera light is ON but the there is no camera display
Could someone help me?
Here is the code

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

cap=cv.VideoCapture(0) 
# read webcam untill the end
while (cap.isOpened()):
    # capture frame by frame
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        # to display frame
        cv.imshow("Frame",frame)
    else:
        break

cv.waitKey(1)
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you put waitKey in wrong place, I hope below code will work !

```
import cv2 as cv

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
# read webcam untill the end
while (cap.isOpened()):
    # capture frame by frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        # to display frame
        cv.imshow("Frame", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break


cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

@tahir mehmood. I modified your code, and I tested it. Worked well.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

cap=cv.VideoCapture(0) 
# read webcam untill the end
while (cap.isOpened()):
    # capture frame by frame
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    cv.imshow("Frame",frame)
    cv.waitKey(1)
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```